# Calling methods on interface pointers in Go

Tags: pointers, interface, go

I'm still sort of wrapping my head around the finer details of interfaces and pointers in Go. I've run into an issue with a simple type containing a pointer to [net.Conn](http://golang.org/pkg/net/#Conn). When I attempt to call a method (Close) on the pointer, I'm receiving `type *net.Conn has no field or method Close`

Here's a trivial example highlighting the issue: http://play.golang.org/p/Q4LB0wi6Tk

What's the proper way to call `Close()` here?

Comment: I've been messing with Go for few months, coming from C++/Delphi etc - ran into the same confusions - some of my questions about it are up here. Take it from the _GoPhers_ guys on here and forget about your notions from other languages - Go looks like C, but doesn't act like it...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Short answer is "Don't use pointers to interfaces". There's rarely any need for them, and you end up with confusing errors like you see.

You would also never use `new()` to create a pointer to an empty interface. Interfaces are satisfied implicitly by a concrete type.

Comment: Ok, that's fair and I've definitely read that before. My question then is; The underlying type behind net.Conn must be allocated somewhere. Is it not worth worrying about passing a copy of net.Conn all over the program? That seems inefficient on the surface, but maybe my understanding of pass-by-reference/value is skewed from other languages.

Comment: @uidzer0 `net.Conn` is a very small, 2 word structure. It's faster to copy it around than to dereference a pointer.

Comment: @uidzer0, also forget about pass-by-reference -- everything in Go is pass-by-value (actually, that's the case with most languages). Pointers are just another value you can pass.

Answer (score 10):

A net.Conn is a small (two-word) structure. If the implementation is a pointer, then the net.Conn holding that implementation is like a pointer too. See http://research.swtch.com/interfaces for an description of how interfaces work under the hood.

Comment: Thanks Russ, JimB solidified my line of thought on passing pointers around. I just wanted to say thanks for the detailed writing you've published. I've found myself on your site countless times.